# Can I use gevent-socketio with cornice?

Tags: gevent-socketio

I need some web socket functionality for monitoring some tasks, is gevent-socketio good fit for back end websocket implementation? Also can I use gevent-socketio with pyramid cornice (running on openshift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible, but not a very good idea overall because project hasn't found a leader or any updates since Dec 2015 https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/commit/1c84627980c0b77f8f9005fdbcc916ca33d0e4d1 in addition gevent monkey patches python's stdlib (which I personally don't like).
since python 3.4 asyncio is part of stdlib https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html I'll investigate housleyjk/aiopyramid as an alternative